# How to create a desktop shortcut that launches Cygwin and tails a particular file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin, dry

I would like to have a desktop shortcut open cygwin so that I can tail a log file.

Currently I perform the following steps manually:

> 1. Start cygwin
> 2. cd dev/server/logs
> 3. tail -f error.log

I would like to automate the three steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Windows shortcut to the following target...

`C:\cygwin\bin\tail.exe -f "C:\Path\to\the\error.log"`

...assuming that's where your tail executable is. Doing `which tail` in a Cygwin shell should confirm that.

That should run the binary in a cmd window. Do `Ctrl-C` to stop it.

EDIT: Oh, one thing I forgot... This might require "C:\cygwin\bin" in your PATH env variable.

Comment: works, but doesn't act like tail. EG, I want to hit CarriageReturn and put some empty lines in the log.

Comment: C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -ha -e bash --login -c "tail -f error.log" [link](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-07/msg00626.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason to perform the `tail` operation from cygwin shell?
If not, you can use the [tail for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and create a shortcut that will point to `tail.exe -f error.log`

If for some reason, you require cygwin shell, try Andy's approach, that should work for you.

Comment: Costa's approach is simpler than what I had suggested -- try his if you need cygwin.